# Automated SQL deployment task in azure devops release pipeline for linux OS

Tags: sql, linux, azure-devops

Trying to add an task in azure devops release pipeline for SQL deployment where the DB's are present in Linux OS VM and didnt get any task in release pipeline. For windows sql deployment we have an task (Azure SQL DacpacTask) to add and execute release pipeline, Same way i am looking for linux OS release pipeline tasks for SQL DB Deployments to execute. So please let me know task Details for the same

Thanks,
Madhu.

Comment: Found this tutorial: https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/deploymentgroups/ and this task: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroupV0/README.md, which might be helpful.

Comment: Hi, Actually this SQL server deploy task which is getting added under deployment group job supports only windows OS, but not for linux OS, so I'm looking option for the sqldb deployment which has been installed in linux VM

Answer (score 6):

> Automated SQL deployment task in azure devops release pipeline for linux OS

Just as you know, Azure SQL Dacpac Task currently supported **only** for Windows-based agent system. MS team are adding this to their backlog and will consider adding this support in the future.

As workaround, you could try to following info:

> 1. Using bash script task,
>
>    - Install MS SQL tools on linux agent
>    - Use bash script task to run script.
>    - Reference - [Create and run SQL Server Agent jobs on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-run-sql-server-agent-job?view=sql-server-2017)
> 2. You can use Azure RG task and execute stored procedure as part of the ARM template
>    Reference - [Copy data from Azure Blob Storage to Azure SQL DB with stored procedure](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-data-factory-blob-to-sql-copy-stored-proc)

Reference from [Azure SQL Publish not supported on Linux build agent](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/8408)